# Gap above ContentView / not the same height as UIScrollview - xib

Tags: swift, swift3, uiscrollview, scrollview, xib

Issue: gap above where contentView starts.  Should be 0.

Despite setting the content view top bottom leading and trailing to 0, the content view has a gap at the top.  I am using auto layout only.

**Scrollview background is blue** &

**Content view is grey** for easy viewing.

If I set the content view to equal heights as the scroll view, I get an error.  And this doesn't seem like the right approach away.  According to this setting equal height is optional:

[Apple auto layout scrollview page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html)

I do set equal widths.

Entire Screen:

[image]

Top of Scroll view:

[image]

Bottom of scroll view -> this is right - flush with bottom of scroll view (not sure if that matters)

[image]

Constraints:

[image]

Subview constraints:

[image]

[image]

Please help!!  Also I am using xib files - not sure if that matters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice that the gap is equal in height to the navigation bar.

The gap is there because by default iOS assumes that when using a translucent navigation bar, scroll views (and their subclasses like table views) begin at the top of the screen, behind the translucent navigation bar.

iOS then assumes you do not want your content hidden behind the translucent navigation bar, so it applies a top content inset to any scroll view, of height equal to the navigation bar height.

This behavior can be overridden in two ways:

1. Unmark `Adjust Scroll View Insets` on the view controller (see image below)
2. Make your navigation bar not translucent. If you're using a Storyboard, select the navigation controller that contains the affected view controller, and unmark the `Translucent` checkbox.

[image: How to disable Adjust Scroll View Insets]

Comment: That's odd because this does not happen to the content above it, only the scroll bar.  I will test and let you know.  Thanks!